# CakePHP + Facebook Graph API

Tags: cakephp, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp-1.3

I wanna integrate Facebook's new Graphs API with my CakePHP application. Can some one help me if there is some kind of a plugin.

Mainly looking at the following functionality

1. Facebook Login
2. Publishing on the Users Wall
3. Inviting Users Friends.
4. Give access to the persons Facebook page and post and retrieve content of the page.
5. Post content to the facebook page's wall of the application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can recommend [Nick Baker's CakePHP Facebook plugin](http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/229/CakePHP_Facebook_Plugin_Auth_Facebook_and_more). It's easy enough to set up.